# How to display badges in iOS app in phonegap with pushNotification.?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

In **push notification.java** i had give `payload.setBadge(1);` when I push message it set's the badge value to 1. Again when i push message it is setting to 1. It is not incrementing the value. I had written the incremental code in iOS native code

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber
numberOfBadges+badges;
```

Answer (score 2):

The value as given in the push notification is always displayed. It will not increment.
You will need to keep track of badge value server side and push the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.could you please tell me how to do it in server side?

Comment: Well you keep track of the bag number for each user server side. We the user opens the app it should tell the server to reset the badge count.

Comment: Can you give a detailed example/explanation on how to get this done?

Comment: I can not, since this depends very much on the server side technology used, the design of you data base and what not. You should just try to implemented yourself and if you run into issue post as a new question of stack overflow.